# Google "shared drive" vs "shared with me"

Tags: google-drive-shared-drive

Can someone explain how Google's "shared drive" and "shared with me" directories differ?

One of my colleagues just granted me access to the team's files, but I noticed they don't fall under my usual "shared drive". Instead, I have to access everything through my "shared with me" directory. This is rather annoying because I find the "shared with me" directory is cluttered with a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Shared drive usually means there are 2 owners to a file while shared with me means that the owner of the file has given you permissions to use their file

Comment: If the owner decided to grant me ownership, would that then switch it to my "shared drive"? I see I can still edit it...I guess it boils down to owner vs editor